# Linux prints many Thread stack info, is this an issue?

Tags: java, c++, linux, multithreading

I have used command [pstack PID] （PID is my tomcat PID）, Linux prints many Thread stack info , details as below.
I am not sure so many Threads are correct or not ?
any idea? if this is an issue, what should I do to make threads be fewer ?

[please check threads info here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tKfx.png)

Comment: Why you suspect that you get incorrect result?

Comment: Using `jstack` or `kill -3` is more likely to produce readable results. The JVM has many threads of its own.

Comment: Thanks @talex may be these threads are correct.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey , yes I used jstack , found that there are some dubbo threads. may be these threads are all correct.